# Outlook 2007 displaying error message .pst file in use and cannot be accessed

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm receiving this error message when trying to forward or delete emails. I've closed outlook and rebooted the computer. The computer is not backing up to my knowledge.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe a file system issue. Try to perform a scandisk.

Comment: close outlook -> make sure the process is not in task manager -> check the properties of the pst file and remove the readonly check mark if present and try again

Answer (score 0):

First thing I'd suspect is an improperly closed or damaged .pst file, which often can be fixed [with Microsoft's tool](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-Outlook-Data-Files-pst-and-ost-25663bc3-11ec-4412-86c4-60458afc5253). For  more help on locating the executable see [MSOutlook.info](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/77).

If that doesn't fix the issue, use a tool such as [LockHunter](http://lockhunter.com/) to see if some other process is locking it.

Comment: Thanks - that's actually what it was - a damaged file which I fixed with Microsoft's repair tool. Thanks!